# WordPress redirecting from example.com/login to example.com/wp-login.php - how to change it?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How can I change default redirection in WordPress from `/login` to `/wp-login.php`? - I don't want that redirection. I want to have something else at `example.com/login`but I can't find it in WordPress, and I don't want lost it during updates.
I will be also grateful for some link to codex if there something that can helps me ;)

**Edit:**

I want to install something different than WordPress in folder `login` under address `example.com/login`, but WordPress automatically redirecting me from `example.com/login` to `example.com/wp-login.php`. I don't want that - I want see content from `example.com/login`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paste this within your `.htaccess` file on your project root. Also must be placed on top of Wordpress Rewriterules.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-login\.php [R=301,L]
```

**Full code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-login\.php [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you don't have any post/page with slug name `login`.

**Edited:**

If you need to map the URL instead of redirect just remove `R=301` flag.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ wp-login\.php [L]
```

Also if you want to see the `login` in URL after logged out. Place this function in your `functions.php` file of your theme.

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'login_redirect');

function login_redirect() {
    wp_redirect(site_url( 'login' ));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanx man, I've added this line but this is still redirecting to 'wp-login.php'. Funny thing is that in two different wordpress installations I can create "login" directory in page directory and this redirecting doesn't work - I see content from this folder (i.e. index.html). But on this one redirection is still working.
I have no idea why?

Comment: @marek You don't need to create directory for it. Remove the Directory and try with this `siteurl.com/login` it will redirect you to `siteurl.com/wp-login.php` and yes `wp-login.php` will appear in url because you said in your question you need redirection.

Comment: Oh crap... I wasn't clear enough - sorry. 
My goal is to use '/login' link for something different than 'wp-login.php', and I don't want this automatic redirection.

Comment: thank you for your help. I think there is something different to do, because it doesn't work. I need to rethink this problem - maybe I asked about wrong things...

Comment: @marek Whats not working? please elaborate more by editing your question.

Comment: @marek Have you tried removing rewriterules from `.htaccess`? You can simply type `site.com/login` it will show you the contents of it. Just  insert `index.html` with contents in your `login` directory. It will show up

Comment: it still don't want to work, but I can use another name for this folder - like '/login-here' and it is working without problems. Like I wrote before - it also works without problems on two others sites, but on this one (this is on client's server) don't want working. Anyway - problem is solving. Thank you for you help!